# How can 関係 be used when there is only one subject?

Tags: syntax, expressions, questions

In my textbook there is a clause that I don't really understand:

なぜ占い好きと関係があるというと、、、

So my understanding takes me this far:

- It's a question asking why 占い好き something
- It's asking why something about relationship(s) - or why relationships to 占い好き exist?

My problem here is: 関係 means relationship right, so I would expect to see at least **two** things references: ie why is there a relationship between 占い好き AND X? ...but here there is no X. To me the question just seems to be: why　is there a relationship between 占い好き ... huh?

Any comments much appreciated!

Comment: Does your textbook really say 「なぜ占い好きと関係があるというと、」, not 「なぜ占い好きと関係がある**か**というと、」?

Answer (score 4):

I think the sentence is about to explain how "IT" is correlated with 占い好き.  And "IT" must be something in the previous sentences or paragraph.  It is common to omit pronoun in some cases.  The full sentence may be:

なぜこれが占い好きと関係があるというと、、、

Comment: 「なぜ～～と関係があるというと、、、」←どこかおかしいと思いません？

Comment: 実はちょっとおかしいとは思いますが、質問がそう書かれていてそのまま使いました。"なぜ関係があるかと言うと" の方がもっと自然でしようね。

Comment: ok, it makes a lot more sense when I think about it from that perspective. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are right. Using two nouns or phrases are expected when you refer to any relationship as follows.

[鶏]{にわとり}と[卵]{たまご}の[関係]{かんけい} The relationship between chicken and egg.

AとBの関係 or AとBは関係がある are broadly used. However, it doesn't necessarily mean you have to always use two nouns as either of them could be omitted or implied.

It is quite common to drop a pronoun or subject in Japanese and without reading further context, it is not possible to know what is referred to in relation to '占い好き'.